Authoritative information/links on (B/D)ER encoding intrinsic errors and how to handle them
Just out of curiosity - (B/D)ER encodings of ASN.1 seem to allow for a few erroneous situations that I have found no spec for and I was wondering if there were people with some authority on the subject out there, that may have written about it. To wit:

A length may be zero when the tag does not allow it.
A length may be given to be longer than there can be bits in the universe (for example a sequence encoding of the form 30 ff ... which would assume a value of length 0x100 to the power of 0x7f).
A tag may be invalid.

Given that each of these is a potential attack vector on the receiver (and also, perhaps, in a lesser form: differences between a 64-bit sender and a 32-bit receiver); is there a 'textbook' way to deal with these situations (other than discard the message)? Have their been opinions written on the subject?
Thanks.
I'm trying to write a DER library. But also seeing if DER, as a choice, is good for me. Most notably, I find the really-long-value-lengths bothersome (and ugly).

ITU-T X.690 is the specification for BER/DER. The word "error" does not appear in it.  I'm not aware of any one having written on the topic.
If a certain type does not have any encodings of length 0 and the length is encoded as 0, I would report that as an invalid length or an invalid value (depending on how you want to look at it).
X.690 8.1.3.5 forbids 0xFF as the starting value for the length octet(s). I don't know how you came up with your interpretation for that, but I think you might want to refer to X.690 8.3.1 for the interpretation of length octets.
If a tag appears that is not valid according to a given schema, I would report that as an error. The TLV format makes it possible to skip over unknown content, but I suppose ignoring content might open the door to attacks.  And anyway, how do you know it wasn't an encoding error (i.e. something else was intended)?  Keep in mind the rules around extensibility - sometimes unexpected tags are explicitly allowed.

Ok. 0xff is indeed forbidden. But 0xfe isn't. Wouldn't that still make length encodings ridiculously long, potentially?

Re-reading 8.1.3.5 and there seems to be an omission in the standard. Or an implicit assumption of a 32-bit platform. Maybe it has to do with the fact that is goes across a page break. But on the first page it says 'bit 8 is one, bit 7-1 encode the amount of bytes to be interpreted as an uint, 0xff shall not be used' and on the second page it says 'you can read max four bytes.' Which isn't apparent from the previous page at all.

So what the standard /should/ have said is: 'allowed values for first byte of the definite long form length encoding are 0x81, 0x82, 0x83 and 0x84'. And that's it.

@Kees-Jan: Subclause 8.1.3.5 does not say that. Please download the correct document.

I have version 0207 as PDF. I think that's the last version. On page 6, at the top, which is the continuation of paragraph numbered 8.1.3.5, the first sentence basically says: you can have max four octets encoding the length of your length encoding. That's 32 bits or, ~4 * 10^9 in other words. What else does it say, according to you?

I cannot figure out what document you have. The latest version is from 2021. You can download it from here:
https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-202102-I/en

0xFE would mean you have the length in the next 127 octets - so yes, a very large length.  Indefinite length encoding could be used to make an arbitrarily long message.  At some point, an implementer would probably have to say "this message is large for me to handle".

You are correct. I misread the text in 8.1.3.5. However, I still find it disturbing that you can define a value to have 256 ^ 126 bits, without providing even a hint as to what you're supposed to do when confronted with something like that (or even some value length of far less a degree).
